# Hide webform after the user's first submission

Tags: webforms

How would I hide the webform in drupal7 after user's(authenticated user) first submission.Later the user should not be able to view the webform again. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your webform, go to the "Form Settings" under "Webform". In case you don't find it, here's the URL: node/Nid/webform/configure (I choose not to remind you of the Nid that you should change :)).

Here, you should see an option for "Per User Submission Limit"-
In your scenario, Limit each user to "1" submission(s) "ever".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried this actually.It doesn't allow the user to resubmit the form. But the requirement is form should be closed after first submission, It should not be seen on site at all. Please suggest.